# DenseVector convolve , how to.(Scala Breeze)

Tags: scala, signal-processing, scala-breeze

Naive user wants to do a simple convolve in Scala Breeze:

```
import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.numerics._
import breeze.signal.support.{OverhangOpt, CanConvolve} // ??

val kernel = DenseVector(1.0, 2.0)
val data   = DenseVector(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
val out    = data.convolve(kernel)
```

Can someone write up a little example how to do this  ?

Comment: Did it work out for you or do you need anything else?

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right way already. Just make sure that you have the latest version of `breeze`, i.e. `0.6-SNAPSHOT`. For example, use the following portions in your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scalanlp" % "breeze_2.10" % "0.6-SNAPSHOT"
    )

resolvers ++= Seq(
        "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
        "Sonatype Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
    )
```

There's no need to import stuff from `breeze.signal.support`, your original example will work just fine:

```
scala> import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.linalg._

scala> import breeze.signal._
import breeze.signal._

scala> convolve(DenseVector(1.0, 2.0), DenseVector(3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0))
res1: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(10.0, 13.0, 16.0)
```

Comment: at least with breeze 2.1.0 the order of arguments has to be reversed, e.g., `convolve(DenseVector(3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0), DenseVector(1.0, 2.0))`.